# Android maps v2 location in all aplication

Tags: android, maps, location

How to get current position in android maps v2, without having to see the map? Let all my application have access to the current location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [`LocationClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) was created for.

See this training lesson for more details on getting current location: http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 0):

You use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to get location. Maps are just to display it.
[This article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) explain how to use it.